# getting inventory error when edit the prodcut from admin

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am working on Magento Enterprise (1.14.1) staging server. When I am update any product from admin I am getting below error which is seems related with Live site database even i am working on staging server (I have searched all possible occurrence which may be related with live database like any custom code, searched in the staging database etc...):

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('[LiveSiteDatabaseName]'@'%') does not exist, query was: UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET product_id = ?, stock_id = ?, qty = ?, min_qty = ?, use_config_min_qty = ?, is_qty_decimal = ?, backorders = ?, use_config_backorders = ?, min_sale_qty = ?, use_config_min_sale_qty = ?, max_sale_qty = ?, use_config_max_sale_qty = ?, is_in_stock = ?, low_stock_date = ?, notify_stock_qty = ?, use_config_notify_stock_qty = ?, manage_stock = ?, use_config_manage_stock = ?, stock_status_changed_auto = ?, use_config_qty_increments = ?, qty_increments = ?, use_config_enable_qty_inc = ?, enable_qty_increments = ?, is_decimal_divided = ? WHERE (item_id='79182')`

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Looking forward for response from expert.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mysql user permissions issue. You need to port the same user privileges from your live DB to your stage DB, to be more specific, your app/etc/local.xml DB username permissions.

`<default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[live_user_name]]></username>`

Add the same privileges and then do a `flush privileges` command.